# Is there any General rule for converting between counting systems

Tags: numbers

If I have a number written in base X, how do I convet it to base Y, or the opposite.

And if there is no general rule, is there a special rule for converting to and from decimal?

Comment: Unless you're talking about string output, everything is base 2 during execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes, there is.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_conversion#Base_conversion)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.